# XML Element Error

Tags: xml

I am in an XML class and my assignment is to create a family tree. I've pretty much finished the document and have been able to figure out and fix the errors displayed.

I am stuck on the current error "The content of element type "Child" must match "(firstName,middleName,surname,maidenName,suffix)". for lines 44,57 and 63. I guess I don't understand why I'm getting the error; it looks to me like I've done things correctly.

Here is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Family [
    <!ELEMENT Family (Father, Mother, Offspring)>

    <!ELEMENT Father (firstName, middleName, surname)>
    <!ELEMENT firstName (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT middleName (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT surname (#PCDATA)>

    <!ELEMENT Mother (firstName, middleName, surname, maidenName)>
    <!ELEMENT maidenName (#PCDATA)>

    <!ELEMENT Offspring (Child)>

    <!ELEMENT Child (firstName, middleName, surname, maidenName, suffix)>
    <!ATTLIST Child 
    ID CDATA #REQUIRED
    gender (Male | Female) "Female"
    birthPlace CDATA #IMPLIED
    birthYear CDATA #IMPLIED>

    <!ELEMENT suffix (#PCDATA)>
]>


<Family>
    <Father>
        <firstName>William</firstName>
        <middleName>Fitzgerald</middleName>
        <surname>Buckley</surname>        
    </Father>
    <Mother>
        <firstName>Ella</firstName>
        <middleName>Ann</middleName>
        <surname>Buckley</surname>
        <maidenName>Fitzgerald</maidenName>
    </Mother>
    <Offspring>
        <Child ID="01" gender="Male">
            <firstName>Gordon</firstName>
            <middleName>Shumway</middleName>
            <surname>Buckley</surname>
            <suffix></suffix>
        </Child>        
        <Child ID="02">
            <firstName>Alice</firstName>
            <middleName>Mae</middleName>
            <surname>Nelson</surname>
            <maidenName>Buckley</maidenName>
            <suffix></suffix>
        </Child>
        <Child ID="03" gender="Male">
            <firstName>Julius</firstName>
            <middleName>Caesar</middleName>
            <surname>Buckley</surname>
            <suffix></suffix>
        </Child>
        <Child ID="04" gender="Male">
            <firstName>Martin</firstName>
            <middleName>Lawrence</middleName>
            <surname>Buckley</surname>
            <suffix></suffix>
        </Child>
    </Offspring>
</Family>
```

Thank you in advance for the assistance!

Kris

Answer (score 1):

The DTD states that all `Child` elements requires a `firstName`, `middleName`, `surname`, `maidenName`, and `suffix`.

```
<!ELEMENT Child (firstName, middleName, surname, maidenName, suffix)>
```

However you have a couple of `Child` elements that does not have a `maidenName`.

```
<Child ID="01" gender="Male">
    <firstName>Gordon</firstName>
    <middleName>Shumway</middleName>
    <surname>Buckley</surname>
    <suffix></suffix>
</Child>        
<Child ID="03" gender="Male">
    <firstName>Julius</firstName>
    <middleName>Caesar</middleName>
    <surname>Buckley</surname>
    <suffix></suffix>
</Child>
<Child ID="04" gender="Male">
    <firstName>Martin</firstName>
    <middleName>Lawrence</middleName>
    <surname>Buckley</surname>
    <suffix></suffix>
</Child>
```

Did you mean to make the `maidenName` optional?

```
<!ELEMENT Child (firstName, middleName, surname, maidenName?, suffix)>
```

Answer (score 0):

You said this:

```
   <!ELEMENT Child (firstName, middleName, surname, maidenName, suffix)>
```

But later you said this:

```
<Child ID="01" gender="Male">
    <firstName>Gordon</firstName>
    <middleName>Shumway</middleName>
    <surname>Buckley</surname>
    <suffix></suffix>
</Child>
```

This Child does not have a maidenName, which you said it has to have.

Try putting

```
<maidenName></maidenName>
```

in the Child, as you have done with suffix... depending on the application that is parsing this, that might work.